# swift - Is there a simple way to keep symlinks when zipping files in swift?

Tags: swift, zip, gzip, tar, symlink

Swift newbie here.

### TL;DR:

The point is to zlib, tar-gzip (preferred) or zip a folder(s) that would (among regular files) contain symbolic links while retain those symlinks (not zipping the actual targets of those into the archive).

### Problem:

Recursive zipping with folders and symlinks in swift seem to be a tough task as only single file/data compressing functions seem to be implemented in Swift natively (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/compressing_and_decompressing_files_with_swift_stream_compression) with no easy hands-on how to use it for complex folder structure.

There are some libraries to help with to handle that, like https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip for zip or https://github.com/1024jp/GzipSwift for gzip, the problem with those is that none I found is handling symlinks as symlinks. Those just follow the symlink and zip the actual file.

I love the marmelroy's Zip syntax where you can simply specify the NSURL of the file/folder to zip and not worry about Data structures, folders structure and content, buffering and all the stuff:

```swift
do {
    let filePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file", withExtension: "zip")!
    let unzipDirectory = try Zip.quickUnzipFile(filePath) // Unzip
    let zipFilePath = try Zip.quickZipFiles([filePath], fileName: "archive") // Zip
}
catch {
  print("Something went wrong")
}
```

the only issue it does not let you work with symlinks or have some custom handlers.

### Question:

Is there a swift package / hack / simple enough way to tar-gzip/zlib/zip a large enough folder that would have symlinks while still keeping those as links? Could you please share some working snippet or point me to right direction?

Would be best if that could be compatible both with macos, ipados and ios.

Thank you!

---

**Update:**

Libraries working with Data structures (like https://github.com/tsolomko/SWCompression or GzipSwift) may have it right but both struggling to represent a folder (containing some files and symlinks in it) as Data structure and doubting writing the whole (e.g. 500 Gb) folder to a byte buffer in memory rather than doing that in small chunks is a good thing (= out of memory issues).

Should be something easy to do, I guess, but struggling to find any **easy** working code **in swift** here that would work for larger folders containing media and symlinks compressing and decompressing those in any format (tar-gzip, zip, or anything else is okay).

Answer (score 2):

Info-ZIP's zip has a `-y` option to store the symbolic link instead of what it references.

tar, *by default*, stores the symbolic links as links. You have to give it an option (`--dereference`) to get it to follow symbolic links.

zlib does not provide any file/directory archive functions. Only compression.

You can run commands like zip or tar from Swift using [Process](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process).

Comment: Thank you so much for your attention / answer, Mark!! I would not bother at all if that would be something to do with zlib/tar/gzip/zip libraries themselves or command-line tools usage options - no problem setting up command-line options for those. Swift programming language libraries that make use of those (including your zlib library) on the other hand do not seem to handle that in any reasonable way (suppose they do, but I did not find any easy way yet, still in process of digging the code), hence this very swift-specific question...

Comment: by the way, I also see the question is incorrectly categorized to "zip" rather than "swift". I am a newbie at stackoverflow and either missing it or otherwise see no way to categorize it myself - just in case you have categorized it to zip, could you please rather change it to "swift" so that a stack of people in swift can find it easier. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "categorized". The question has a set of tags which include both swift and zip. The tags look good, but I just swapped zlib for tar. You can edit the tags by hitting "Edit tags" just to the right of the tags.

Comment: Yeah, tags are alright - by "categorizing" I mean that when you look at the title (in browser tab title that is withing the <title></title> HTML tag, not post title) you can first see "zip -" in "zip - swift - Is there a simple way to keep symlinks when zipping files in swift?" title for the page. Have no idea how it has been chosen to have that first "zip -" in there :confused: Hope it does not affect some internal stackoverflow categorization.

Comment: P.S. This "category - your question text" is on every post in stackoverflow if you take a look at any. e.g. "macos - How do I turn on my mac?". However, why did not it pick up e.g. the first tag for that title, see no logic / have no idea - could it be somebody doing it (semi-)manually on such a number/scale of questions here??

Comment: I didn't downvote the question. You should not make such assumptions. I am guessing that the question was downvoted because you are essentially asking for a library recommendation, as opposed to asking a specific programming question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for what is on topic on stackoverflow.

Comment: I have no idea what you are looking at or seeing for "category - your question text". That is certainly _not_ on every post on stackoverflow. This question has the explicit title _swift - Is there a simple way to keep symlinks when zipping files in swift?_. You put in "swift" (twice), not stackoverflow.

Comment: Asking about any insight here on how to handle symlinks actually or represent a folder as Data structure while buffering it rather than storing in-memory, as I do not think anybody is going to advise on any library (as I have checked all of those and none seem to work fine with symlinks). It is not really a recommendation question. But I got your point!

Comment: Not really, I have put "swift -" into the question's **post title** after I saw the "zip -" is added on **website page** title assuming that could fix it, did not fix. It is now "zip - swift - [rest of the title]". You can see it if you look on the title displayed on the browser tab for this page or looking into page source code <title></title> HTML tag. That is not a question for you, just explaining what I am talking about :-) and sorry that here and not via chat - website suggests me to move commenting to chat but then says I do not have enough reputation to move it to / use chat :-D

Comment: Ah, I see what you're talking about now. A user will not see the HTML title in the tab or list of windows until they have already selected that particular question to look at. So it does not matter for attention to your question. Still, it is annoying when I have a lot of tabs open at the same time, since I'll only see the selected tag. There is no way for you to pick _which_ tag is shown there, unless you have only one tag. It will always use the most popular tag. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127370/should-we-stop-adding-the-most-popular-tag-to-the-html-title-on-every-se-site

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks a lot, Mark! Yes, I must say it is such a shame it is done the way it is done for the moment.